# Update frequency every exact hour

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't know if this is possible but I want to my function run exact once hour, for example, if I run my program 16:23 I want my function to run initialy and then my next run is exactly at 17:00, next execute is 18:00 and so on.

I'm using Tkinter to show some information on display and my function that I want to run once an hour are:

```
api_address = "https://api.hgbrasil.com/weather?woeid=455839"
update_frequency = 10800000  #3H in milisegundos
def url_renova():
    global json_data
    global sunrise
    global sunset

    json_data = requests.get(api_address).json()

    sunrise = json_data['results']['sunrise']
    sunset = json_data['results']['sunset']

    sitesunrise.set(sunrise) #Go to a StrinVar and go to a Entry Widget
    sitesunset.set(sunset)

    sitesunriseEntry.after(update_frequency, url_renova)
```

I already tried with schedule but without success, and while don't work. Thanks for your attetion.

Comment: Maybe you can get the next hour time difference and then sleep for that time? Not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh When I was searching for a solution I don't see how I can get that difference and put only this function to sleep.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. You just have to do a little math to know how many seconds until the top of the hour.

Comment: It's more about how and if it's possible. Can I do this using .after? Or what library I need for that

Comment: You can do it with `after`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily calculate the time left until the top of the hour. There's many ways to do that; I think I would just mod the result from time.time(), like this:

```
import time
# ...
wait_time = -int(time.time()* 1000) % 3_600_000
sitesunriseEntry.after(wait_time, url_renova)
```